# How to use tokens (OAuth ?) with AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, access-token, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have setup an AWS Lambda function using this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-lambda.html). I incorporated AWS API Gateway with my Lambda function using this other [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html).
The second tutorial gave the code below (A) for the lambda function to accept tokens. For testing purposes, I successfully used Postman and passed in "allow/deny/unauthorized" in the header to access different parts of the lambda function.

**My question** is how can I incorporate real tokens into API Gateway/AWS Lambda? I see in the comments (in the code block below - A) it states " *// Call oauth provider, crack jwt token, etc.* ". I am not sure how to do so.... I have been searching online for examples of this (because this most be a common thing people do right?) and have not been able to find a solid example of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Excuse my limited knowledge on this subject.

My end goal is to :

1. Have unauthenticated users from a mobile app hit the API Gateway endpoint that would then call my lambda function to validate the token.
2. If the token has been validated, another lambda function will be called to do stuff.

```js
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    // Call oauth provider, crack jwt token, etc.
    // In this example, the token is treated as the status for simplicity.

    switch (token) {
        case 'allow':
            context.succeed(generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            context.succeed(generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            context.fail("Unauthorized");
            break;
        default:
            context.fail("error dawg");
    }
    };

    var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
      var authResponse = {};
      authResponse.principalId = principalId;
      if (effect && resource) {
          var policyDocument = {};
          policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
          policyDocument.Statement = [];
          var statementOne = {};
          statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
          statementOne.Effect = effect;
          statementOne.Resource = resource;
          policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
          authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
      }
      return authResponse;
   }
```

Comment: What is your provider? While OAuth is a 'standard', many implement it differently, so specifying what system is generating your tokens will help people suggest methods for validating it.

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear in my question, but I was hoping to get pointed to some nice examples / see an example of this. I know very little on this subject. Maybe I am thinking too much of tokens working with AWS and rather I should first read about tokens?

Answer (score 3):

Examples:

1. **Example using a self-encoded access token**
   [Introducing custom authorizers in Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway) ([AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/))
2. **Example using an unrealistic access token**
   [Enable Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorization](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) ([AWS Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/))
3. **Example using an external authorization server**
   [Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorizer + OAuth](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/custom_authorizer) ([Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/))

Comment: Thank you! The first link is very helpful. I have a couple more questions...   1) Is it a good idea to use JWT to validate unauthenticated users?   2) If JWT is the route to go, how can I generate a new token for the user? I have read [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/07/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) that tokens need to be reissued.